# Unity WebRequest POST request to python app | How to receive data in python?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, request

I am using unity to send a post request to an URL of my python app.

The unity code seems to work:

```
List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("feedback=UnityGameFeedback"));

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://www.example.com/site/give-game-feedback", formData);
//www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
yield return www.SendWebRequest();

if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
    Debug.Log(www.error);
} else {
    Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
}
```

I am trying to receive the data on server but so far nothing works:

```
@app.route('/site/give-game-feedback', methods=["POST"])
def give_game_feedback():

    if request.method == "POST":
        #data_received = json.loads(request.data)

        try:
            print (request.POST)
        except Exception:
            print ("request.POST FAIL")

        try:
            print (request.POST.get('feedback'))
        except Exception:
            print ("request.POST.get('feedback') FAIL")

        try:
            print (json.loads(request.POST.get('data')))
        except Exception:
            print ("json.loads(request.POST.get('data') FAIL")

        if len(request.data.strip()) > 0:
            new_feedback = Report(report=request.data, date_created=datetime.today())
            db_session.add(new_feedback)
            db_session.commit()
            return 'done'

        return 'failed'

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Some of my other tries:

```
try:
    print (request.POST['feedback'])
except Exception:
    print ("request.POST['feedback'] FAIL")

try:
    print (request.form['feedback'])
except Exception:
    print ("request.form['feedback'] FAIL")

try:
    print (request.get('feedback'))
except Exception:
    print ("request.get('feedback') FAIL")
```

I am blindly trying out every syntax. I also tried changing the content type of the unity request to JSON, but still no results.

I often get this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

But `json.loads` does not help here aswell.

Only this gives no errors on the server:

```
request.data
```

But its also some random nonsense, probably encoded data, which is useless. In my case it looks like this:

```
\x0d0a2d2d42596730563572396262306b74526d6f4272543346576a4f75564a4446577a5939756c33553550720d0a436f6e74656e742d446973706f736974696f6e3a20666f726d2d646174610d0a43 ...
```

Comment: Need some more data on this, I'd suggest using `except Exception as e: print(e)` to get the full exception and write it over here. Also you can use a scanner, such as Burp Suite, to intercept the request and view the headers and body. I would also try `string json = JsonUtility.ToJson();` the form data before you send it and also encoding it to UTF-8, `byte[] jsonToSend = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(json);`

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is the solution.

Use `WWWForm` instead of `List<IMultipartFormSection>`:

```
WWWForm formData = new WWWForm();
formData.AddField("feedback", "TEST");

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://www.example.com/site/give-game-feedback", formData);
yield return www.SendWebRequest();

if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
    Debug.Log(www.error);
} else {
    Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
}
```

In python you can access the value with this:

```
request.form['feedback']
```